# faced error on azure portal on purchasing of template There were validation errors

Tags: azure

While creating template on available image of Virtual Machine , I downloaded template from that image and uploaded while creating template faced below error:

> Deployment template validation failed: 'Circular dependency detected
>   on resource:
>   '/subscriptions/1e193df3-046f-49c6-af40-058c742e5d86/resourceGroups/ManojResource/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/TaskOneVM'.
>   Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.
>   (Code: InvalidTemplate)
>
> https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json
>   unable to load schema from above url and no schema request service available {error faced on above line}

Comment: What template are you using ?

Comment: custom deployment and image of Ubantu virtual machine and in that application is installed

Comment: On editor it is showing error--Unable to load schema from 'https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json'. No schema request service available

Comment: You mean that you're creating and editing a template by yourself ? or Refer to another  template? If possible , you can post your template or template link in the question.

Comment: Indeed, you can tell us what do you want to achieve with template.Such as creating a VM with a existing image...

Comment: The task of creating a new VM with the application installed on it needs to be  automated. Create a template to make a new VM from image

Comment: Did you referred this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-custom-image-new-storage-account) and this [tempate](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-user-image)?

Comment: No, I will check. Thanks :)

Comment: You can just click `deploy to Azure` to use it :-) This is for the custom image from VHD, not managed Image. I assume that you're using an image from VHD.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT Thank you done with Task.